# Getting a p-value from a histogram?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

A hypothetical HIV vaccine trial involving 20,000 participants—10,000 in the vaccine group and 10,000 in the placebo group—had the following results: 6.3 infections per 1000 in the vaccine group and 9.0 infections per 1000 in the placebo group.

I ran a computer simulation to predict possible outcomes of the trial if the null hypothesis is true—that is, if vaccinated and unvaccinated people are equally likely to contract HIV. I ran 1000 virtual trials of 20,000 people (10,000 per group) assuming that the vaccine is ineffective. Outcomes are expressed as excess infections in the placebo group. Here are the results of the 1000 virtual trials displayed as a histogram.

1. Roughly estimate the (two-sided) p-value associated with the trial’s outcome from the histogram. 
   2.From the simulation, I learn that the statistic ‘excess infections in the placebo group’ follows a normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation (standard error) of 12.3. Use this information to calculate the two-sided p-value more precisely than in (1).
   [image]

Comment: Just two questions: how did you conclude that the statistic ‘excess infections in the placebo group has a mean of 0? This is not in accordance with the initial hypothesis of better result in vaccinated subjects. Also, the histogram might suggest that the mean could be higher than zero as expected (in particular, if the excess on the y-axis is expressed in infections per 1000 subjects, it could be possible that the mean is around the expected value of 2.7). The second question is: how was simulation exactly performed? Details may be relevant to ask your question.

Comment: @Anatoly: the zero mean obviously follows from the null hypothesis: "I ran a computer simulation to predict possible outcomes of the trial if the null hypothesis is true—that is, if vaccinated and unvaccinated people are equally likely to contract HIV." Of course, it's wrong to say the zero mean is deduced from the histogram. It's deduced from the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) if you've simulated the excess infections under the null then you have numerically estimated the sampling distribution. Just calculate the fraction of the simulation results that are $\geq 3.3$ or $\leq -3.3$ This is the two-sided p-value for your observed placebo excess.

For 2) you are not using your simulation, but the $\mathcal{N}(0,12.3)$ distribution in lieu of the simulation results. Now, just calculate $2(1-\Phi(\frac{3.3}{12.3}))$. This is based on the normal distribution.

Compare results.